# Moving a file somewhere else on hard drive

Tags: sublimetext3

I have been searching for a way to move a project folder to a different location on my drive and still be able to use it in Sublime Text. After moving the folder, Sublime Text will not save changes because it says the file is missing.

Comment: Like most programs, Sublime keeps track of files and folders based on their path. If you move them, it can't know where they moved to (only that they're gone). If you want to move files/folders, you need to close them in Sublime and then re-open them at the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Every editor stores a project location as a reference. Your sublime text is still looking for files from your previous location.
You can simply add a new project choosing you new project location.